# Center $Z(G)$ of noncommutative group $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given a noncommutative finite group $G$ (and $G$ is also *not* a $p-$group) I’m trying to prove that the center $Z(G)$ of this group must be trivial. But do not fully inderstand the method of the proof.

From the Lagrange’s theorem it follows that $|Z(G)|$ must divide $|G|$. Also it cannot be such way that $|Z(G)|=|G|$ because then $G$ is commutative.

But then I do not know in way I need to go. Or maybe it is not true or may be only in some cases?
Give some idea!

Comment: What makes you think that it must be trivial?

Comment: There's no way it has to be trivial.  Consider dihedral groups for even-sided polygons.

Comment: Consider the direct sum of a commutative group and a noncommutative group...

Comment: This is simply not true. The centre of a non-commutative simple group is trivial - the centre is a normal subgroup. But you can take a direct product of an abelian group $A$ with a non-commutative simple group (say $A_5$), and get a group whose centre is $A$.

Comment: A $p$-group has nontrivial center; but this is just a *sufficient* condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The center of a non-commutative group need not be trivial, even if we insist that the group not be a $p$-group.  For example if $G, G'$ are groups then the center of $G \times G'$ is $Z(G) \times Z(G')$.  So, for an explicit example, if $S_3$ is the symmetric group on $3$ letters then $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times S_3$ is a non-commutative group which is not a $p$-group but has a center isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I did some mistake in my considerations.